# AIX build getting symbol from wrong .a library but works well on legacy HP-UX

Tags: ld, aix

On a large legacy build on HP-UX with many static libraries. Two of which have the same function, call it "dupxyz".  All works fine as dupxyz is pulled out of the desired module.

On the AIX system we are migrating to, and trying to use the same build process, dupxyz gets pulled out of the wrong -l library, despite the proper library being listed first on the command line and the wrong one last.

Been hunting for "why?"  I'm new to this depth of AIX linkers and it's been long time ago since I was this deep in UNIX style linkers.

Questions:
[1] Is there a way to, on the AIX ld command line, to force the pesky symbol to be loaded from the correct .a library early on, OR
[2] Block the symbol from being taken from the wrong library?

Comment: If you don't get help here, there used to to be separate "world" of AIX savy on the ittoolbox dot com (you have to join, and then find the right "group" to join (at least that is how it used to be) ). ...  ... Also if you're not aware IBM has a support website for it's tools where unique knowledge was kept. Sorry don't have the exact URL , but with RedHat/IBM it has likely changed. Goodl luck.

Comment: For the linking process you can create a modified version of the *.a library that doesn't contain the problematic object modul (`ar dv foo.a member.o`)